# procurar texto em todos os ficheiros de uma répertorio

Tags: sublime-text-2, notepad++, dreamweaver

Existe uma forma de procurar um determinado texto em todos ficheiros de um repertorio usando editores tais como : **dreamweaver** **sublime-text-2** ou **notepad++** ?

Comment: Tem que ser pelo editor ? Se fosse pelo bash do linux é bem fácil.

Comment: Com Notepad++  você pode ir em menu "Localizar > Localizar em Arquivos" (Find in files") Ctrl+Shift+F

Comment: Acredito que em todos o atalho é o mesmo. Sério que não achou isso no Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Notepad++ acione `CTRL + SHIFT + F`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

No sublime text você pode usar o `CTRL + SHIFT + F`, os campos que irão aparecer:

Find - O texto que você quer encontrar

Where - Local onde estao os arquivos (`<project>`  é o default)

Replace - Texto que você quer usar para substituir

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]